# Is there a name for this feature

Tags: javascript, string, variables, methods

I was playing around with javascript in VSCode, and I tried to operate string methods on values instead of variables. Here's what I mean:

```
let a = "Hello World".includes('H');
```

Is there an actual name for this feature of javascript? And is there an actual situation where this is useful?

Comment: Are you mentioning `var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.includes("world");` this

Comment: No, there isn't: you're just calling a function on an object, in this case you have a string (whether it's a string primitive like `"whatever"` or a variable that points to a string does not matter), and you're calling its `inclucdes()` function. This is also not "a feature a javascript": this is how almost every procedural programming language that has data types with classes/prototypes/property functions/etc works. `"a".length()` is the same as `let s = "a"; s.length();` because `s` is just an alias for `"a"`. That's how variables work.

Comment: All javascript objects have a prototype chain. So in this case, whether you define the string as a variable or a literal doesn't matter because it is still a string object and therefore has access to the string object prototype chain. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: Appreciate your comment @JeremyK. Thanks!